# Inspect Font of UI element

Tags: fonts, windows-10, inspect, accessibility-insights

I want to detect what is the Font of some Button in an application.

I have tried [Inspect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects) From Windows Kit, but as I see, it does not have Font property for the UI elements. The same with [Accessibility Insights](https://accessibilityinsights.io/docs/en/windows/getstarted/inspect/).

[GUIPropView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gui_prop_view.html) has Font property, but it is empty for the Button I am inspecting.

Can you advise of another tool that can show the font?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can only **possibly** view the font of a button using Inspect or Accessibility Insights for Windows if the [UIA Text pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-text-pattern) is available on an element.

Most of the time, the Text pattern won't be available.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to inspect the font that was being used on a
form I needed to, by using [Windows Detective](https://windowdetective.sourceforge.io/).

1. select your window on the left or use the eye-dropper tool.
2. choose *View Properties*
3. the **Font** section is near the bottom.